# IPSec settings greuyed out in Add new connection dialog - Fedora36

Tags: fedora, networkmanager, vpn, ipsec

I would like to add a Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol (L2TP) VPN connection in Network Manager and need to change the IPSec settings but the button is greyed out: [image]

I've installed the `NetworkManager-strongswan` package with `dnf` but it looks like, I might still be missing something. Can someone help me out, here?

Answer (score 0):

With NetworkManager-l2tp 1.20.4 and earlier, there is a bug with the detection of the new Libreswan 4.9 as a result of it using a shortened version string, see bug report:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2138290

NetworkManager-l2tp 1.20.6 has a fix for the Libreswan 4.9 detection issue.

If you want NetworkManager-l2tp to use strongswan (which you have already installed), you will need to remove libreswan with:

```
sudo rpm -e libreswan
```

NetworkManager-l2tp will then fallback to using strongswan

Comment: Hi Douglas, Thank you for this. I followed your instructions, restarted NetworkManager but still have the greyed out IPSec Settings button

Comment: It looks like you are using KDE `plasma-nm-l2tp` rather than `NetworkManager-l2tp-gnome`.

The Fedora 36 `plasma-nm-l2tp` package will need the following plasma-nm commit backported to handle the detection for Libreswan 4.9 https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-nm/-/commit/b1f34a86384e1dd82dd87f133e25f0584cabfb84

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a workaround for the `plasma-nm-l2tp` detection of the Libreswan 4.9 [simplified version message](https://github.com/libreswan/libreswan/commit/7f98dc530a2f0f893494b92ac29cc2ced19688ac) generated by the `/usr/sbin/ipsec` script, the simplified version message change can be reversed by running the following:

```bash
sudo sed -e '/"Libreswan /s/Libreswan /Linux Libreswan /' -i /usr/sbin/ipsec
```

Which results in the Libreswan version message changing from "Libreswan 4.9" to "Linux Libreswan 4.9" like it did with older versions, so should make `plasma-nm-l2tp` happy.

Alternatively if you would prefer to use strongswan with NetworkManager-l2tp instead of libreswan, just issue the following:

```bash
sudo dnf install strongswan
sudo rpm -e libreswan
```

Comment: Fedora Bugzilla report for this KDE `plasma-nm` issue is https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2138683